# extract saxaphone riff

Tags: software

What are the steps that I need to take to extract the intro saxaphone riff from [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MGYV006FoE)?

I'm using bitwig, but I guess that these softwares are all pretty equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Hire a sax player and some studio time

Edit: @JoshP swiftly deleted this answer, but it was not intended to be a snarky answer.  I interpreted the question as "How do I Get The Sound of this Saxophone Line Isolated"

And in the case where it is mixed down with a simultaneous trumpet sound, as well as drums, etc., you will only get garbage by trying to filter it out.  Basically attempting to reiterate the last answer, and add a helpful suggestion which is that a good sax player could replicate this line pretty well, and with much better quality than a software filter.

Since this answer was deleted, that entire conversation just died...

@Joshp, ever heard of a downvote, and a comment asking for clarification?

The ridiculous amount of unilateral censorship and hating on people for expressing their ideas is why this website is a graveyard with little activity...it really pissed me off to see my thoughts Junked for no reason.  I've been coming to this website for years, since before it was on SE, and this shit has happened before but I'm sick of it, and I'm done here.

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly impossible to separate individual instruments from mixed song.

One crude option for song like this is to apply high and low pass filters in such way, that you will eliminate frequencies of other instruments. Cymbal in this particular record has character of noise so there is also chance to remove it with noise reduction processor.

Overall it is not possible without sacrificing quality of the result.